# How do I call static from the class I created in c#

Tags: c#

```
namespace HelloDogs
```

{
    class Dog
    {
        private string barkSound;
        private string breed;       // Added dogHeight, dogColor and noOfLegs to
        private int dogHeight;     // the private variable
        private string dogColor;
       private static int noOfLegs;

```
    public string Breed
    {
        get { return breed; }
        set { breed = value; }
    }

     public static int NoOfLegs
     {
     get{return noOfLegs; }      // I created properties to encapsulate the variables
        set {noOfLegs = value; }   // dogHeight, dogColor and noOfLegs using the properties
    }

    public int DogHeight
    {
        get {return dogHeight;}
        set{dogHeight = value;}
    }

    public string DogColor
    {
        get {return dogColor;}
        set{ dogColor = value;}
    }

    private string dogSpeech;

    public Dog()
    {
        barkSound = "Jack!";
        breed = "cocker spaniel";
    }
    // Added a new constructor below that takes the  following parameters
    public Dog(int h,string b, string c )
    {

        dogHeight = h;
        dogColor = c;
        breed = b;
    }
    // A private method to check the dogHeight if true or false 
    private bool IsBig(int x)
     {
        if (x < 50)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

// Change the GetSpeech method below to display all details about the dog
        public string GetSpeech()
        {

```
        dogSpeech = "Hello, I am a " + breed + " , " + dogHeight  +  "cm"  +  "," 
            + dogColor +  "."  + barkSound ;
        return dogSpeech;

        if(IsBig(dogHeight))
        {
            return dogSpeech = "You are big ";
        } else
        {
            dogSpeech = " You are not big enough";
        }
    }
    public void SetSound(String barkSound)
    {
        this.barkSound = barkSound;

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Code dumps do not make a good question. To get help, make a tiny example, and ask a very specific question.

Comment: ok thanks, I will be very specific next time and I will make my example tiny for quick understanding

Answer (score 0):

Calling static from class please see this in msdn
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx